Assertion for json array in Karate using match contains
I am seeing a potential issue with match contains assertion. Below is  the scenario with assertion statements
Scenario: 

 * def statusEnum = ["ACTIVE", "PENDING"] 
 * def actualStatus = ["PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING"] 

 * match actualStatus contains statusEnum // actual array does not contain expected item - ACTIVE
 * match statusEnum contains actualStatus // FAILS actual array length is less than expected - 2:3

The first assertion statement works as expected and fails with an error that the array does not contain ACTIVE.
The 2nd match statement fails because of array size. As karate documentation states size and order of the actual array does not matter, I was expecting this statement to pass.
Is this a bug in karate?
Karate documentation link- https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#json-arrays
Note:-  The array actualStatus is from JSON response. So its size, values and order will vary.

After reading your original post and the comments in @cyrilgeorge153's answer, I think what you are trying to achieve is the following * match each actualStatus == '#? statusEnum.includes(_)' . This solution also allows you to add more elements to your ENUM without having to update the validation expression.
Scenario: Validate elements against ENUM
* def statusEnum = ["ACTIVE", "PENDING"]
* def actualStatus = ["PENDING", "PENDING", "PENDING"]
* match each actualStatus == '#? statusEnum.includes(_)'

here is what each part of that syntax means
The following line tells karate to iterate over each element in actualStatus and assert that each element meets the condition on the right hand side
* match each actualStatus ==

this line
'#? statusEnum.includes(_)'

is a bit more contrived where
#? idicates that a custom JS expression follows and tells karate to evaluate it as JS
statusEnum.includes(_) This is the actual condition being checked. The includes method checks if the array statusEnum contains the current element being iterated over from actualStatus
_ the underscore inside of the parenthesis acts as a placeholder for the current element in the array being iterated over and checked.
Another way to think about this validation is by writing it like so
* match each actualStatus == '#? _ == "ACTIVE" || _ == "PENDING"'

The shorthand expessions for #? & the _ stay the same but validation against the enum is split out and statically defined to achieve the same results. The only drawback to this is if your ENUM grows you will have to keep adding the values to every instance of this validation so I suggest going with the first solution in my answer.

Replace contains with contains any
* match statusEnum contains any actualStatus


Thanks @cyrilgeorge153 but that would not work. E.g:-

def actualStatus = ["INACTIVE", "PENDING", "PENDING"]

Changing contains to contains any will pass the scenario for the above actualStatus even though INACTIVE is not one of the expected enums.

In your question you have asked for a solution so that your second assertion needs to be passed irrespective of array size, order of value. I have given answer for that requirement. To be frank, your requirement is really difficult to understand. Normally in API testing we do assert actual response with expected response, here you are doing both. Please correct your question with exact requirement.

Hi @cyrilgeorge153
My requirement is to assert that each of the actual value for status is either ACTIVE or PENDING given that the array size can vary from 1 to many.
I added both statements to my post to highlight the difference between actual behavior and what is mentioned in the documentation.
I hope that clears up any confusion.
